# How do i populate tkinter drop-down box with new data everytime i pressed "refresh"?

Tags: python, sql, database, tkinter, refresh

I have a refresh button that will get the latest data from database everytime i pressed. I can see the new data from terminal but the data couldn't show in the drop down list.

For example:
**New data "newaddded" can be shown in terminal every time i pressed "refresh" :**

[image]

**BUT the "newadded" data cannot be shown in tkinter drop down list :**
[image]

My code:

```py
def MainMenuForm():

    refresh_button = Button(root, text="refresh", command=ListboxContent)
    refresh_button.place(x=130, y=17, width=50, height=22)
    
      JsonPresetLBL = Label(jsonframe, text="JSON Preset:", font=("Calibri", 11, "bold"), fg="black")
      JsonPresetLBL.place(x=200, y=170)
      global options
      options = StringVar(jsonframe)
      options.set("Select ")  # default value
      om1 = OptionMenu(jsonframe, options, *jsonprofileName, command=get)
      om1.place(x=290, y=168, width=100)


def ListboxContent():
    # ==========jsonProfileName================
    cur = con.cursor()
    sqlName = ("select jsonid, jsonprofilename from json")
    # call jsonProfileName
    global jsonprofileName
    jsonprofileName = []
    try:
        cur.execute(sqlName)
        results = cur.fetchall()
        for a in results:
            global data
            data = (a[1])
            jsonprofileName.append(data)
            print(data)
    except:
        print("Error: unable to fetch data")
```

Comment: You ask a question and you delete it soon, what if people are working on the answer and you just delete it.

Comment: @CoolCloud i'm very sorry, caused some question that i asked is not explain properly. So i decided to delete it.

Comment: I dont think you can update a `OptionMenu`, better use `ttk.Combobox`.

Comment: Yes i tried with combobox . But still couldn't update the value

Comment: Use: `ttk.Combobox.config(values=results)`

Comment: I tried with .config but it showed me `missing 1 required positional argument 'self'` Image: [link](https://ibb.co/4ZpW7ZS) [link](https://ibb.co/8MfbsQZ)

Comment: Your supposed to instantiate it first and assign variable to it and then call `config()` on that variable. Just like normal widgets.

Comment: It still cant be show, i still need to reopen the program in order to view new data. Dont know is my writing problem or not. `  TCombobox1 = ttk.Combobox(jsonframe)
TCombobox1.place(x=290, y=168, width=100)
TCombobox1.configure(values=jsonprofileName)
`

Comment: Use `TCombobox1 = ttk.Combobox(jsonframe)` and then later inside the function, say `TCombobox1.config(values=result)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach could be to destroy the old one and place a new one at the same position.

If you use `place`, then you can simply place the new one at the same coordinate, example

```py
from tkinter import *

def refresh():
    global optionmenu
    data=['new','data']
    optionmenu.destroy()
    option.set('')
    optionmenu=OptionMenu(root,option,*data)
    optionmenu.place(x=100,y=50)


root=Tk()

option=StringVar()
data=['hello','world']
optionmenu=OptionMenu(root,option,*data)
optionmenu.place(x=100,y=50)

button=Button(root,text='Refresh',command=refresh)
button.pack(padx=100,pady=100)

root.mainloop()
```

If you use `pack` or `grid`, you will need to have a container `Frame` that will hold the position, example

```py
from tkinter import *

def refresh():
    global optionmenu
    data=['new','data']
    optionmenu.destroy()
    option.set('')
    optionmenu=OptionMenu(op_frame,option,*data)
    optionmenu.pack()


root=Tk()

option=StringVar()
data=['hello','world']

op_frame=Frame(root)
op_frame.pack()
optionmenu=OptionMenu(op_frame,option,*data)
optionmenu.pack()

button=Button(root,text='Refresh',command=refresh)
button.pack(padx=100,pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

**UPDATE**

You could also do it by accessing the `menu` of the `OptionMenu`, clearing it out and rewriting all the options.

```py
def refresh():
    global optionmenu
    data=['new','data']
    menu=optionmenu['menu']
    menu.delete(0,END)
    for d in data:
        menu.add_command(label=d,command=lambda val=d: option.set(val))
```

Comment: For that kind of question, you may consider asking in [codereview.se].

Comment: @Johnnyyy I just recalled another method of doing it and have updated the answer. I am not really sure which method is "lighter" but you can consider using `ttk.Combobox`, the `config` method makes it a little easier.